# Google Drive Authentication URL

Tags: google-drive-api

i cannot understand what to fill in this autherization redirect URL and what dows it do. Can you help me out?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vlg7129slz7fmfx/Google%20Drive%20Redirect%20URI.png

Comment: Your title Says Google Drive your link says Drop box. What exactly are you trying to connect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find all you need to know here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi

Comment: how to get access code after clicking accept on the verification page and what exactly is "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".

Comment: If you have a native application you can either use 'http://localhost' (what I did for mine) or 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
In case you choose localhost the browser window will show a token you have to pass to your native application.
In case of this cryptic string the token will be shown in the adress bar.
If you have a web application you just put in the URL you want to be redirected after the authorisation.

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't add a comment because of low reputation, I have listed as an answer to your comment for- urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

Note: In some cases, although it is possible to listen though localhost, other software (such as a Windows firewall) prevents delivery of the message without significant client configuration.

urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

This value signals to the Google Authorization Server that the authorization code should be returned in the title bar of the browser. This is useful when the client (such as a Windows application) cannot listen on an HTTP port without significant client configuration.

When you use this value, your application can then detect that the page has loaded, and can read the title of the HTML page to obtain the authorization code. It is then up to your application to close the browser window if you want to ensure that the user never sees the page that contains the authorization code. The mechanism for doing this varies from platform to platform.

Comment: great answer, you can use urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto to close html page without use seeing it